# Multi-level Page Tables concepts

Tags: linux, memory-management, x86, operating-system, paging

**3 level page table**

- Which level contains the offset of the page?
- Will the page size of each level, be the same or different?

If the 2nd level and 3rd level page table size is 2^25 Bytes. Each contains    2^9 entries. Page Table Entry size is 4 Bytes. Where (2^25 - 2^9*4)B is used.

How could this be used, or will it be wasted?

**4 level page table**

Which diagram can clarify the clear view of:

- MMU
- Page table
- Page table entry
- Virtual address
- Physical addresses?

Answer (score 5):

> Which level contains an offset of the page?

Pages are not responsible for offset.


Lets do an example which might help you understand:

- **32 bit address space**
- **page size 4096 bytes**
- **2^32 = 4 GB virtual memory**

To reference each byte of the page we will need log(4096) = 12 bits.

Now we need to calculate the number of different pages, that is 4GB/4KB = **1M** pages. 1M is **2^20** different pages. We need 20 bits to reference each page.

Lets do a **2 leve page tables**. The outer one, also called page directory will have **2^10** **entries**, each entry points on a **page table** which also has 2^10 entries.

[image: no description]

10 bits will mark the entry in the PGDIR which points to a page table, after we access the page table we will use the next 10 bits to find the entry which contains the number of physical frame.

Whenever the CPU runs a command, it will use first 20 bits to find the frame, and will use the final 12 bits as reference inside that page.

[image]

Each entry in page table has 32 bits, first 20 to reference the physical frame, and next 12 are flags used to tell who can `read/write` and more...
[image]